# how to call a matlab function with arguments and capture output in java?

Tags: java, cross-compiling, matlab

I would like to know how to call and execute a matlab function with parameters  using java and capture the output in java.

Comment: What OS? Windows? Linux? Something you invented?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: gud one. Am working on both windows and linux. However i need how to run and grab the output of matlab function with params in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see different options.

1. Create a JAR from your code, using the Builder JA.
2. Use [matlabcontrol](https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/%20matlabcontrol), which is a 3rd party automation server:
3. Use the MatlabControl.java, which allows to run matlab code from java running within the matlab JRE. [enter link description here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html)
4. While the Builder JA is expensive and the options 2 and 3 might get you in truble with future matlab versions, using the matlab [CLI](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html%20cli) is another possibility which probably does not cause any maintenance. For parameters and return, I would use a file. The main disadvantage is a new matlab session starting for each call, which needs some time.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.